# userAccountControl attribute for OpenLdap

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I installed OpenLDAP on Ubuntu 18. Added some users with basic information like name, username, and email. I want to set and get the `userAccountControl` attribute for users so that I can set/get the values `userMustchangePassword, cannotChangePassword, password never expires or Locked out`, etc. `userAccountControl` attribute is used for AD but not for OpenLDAP. Can somebody help guide me to achieve this task?

Note: I am using Novell.Directory.Ldap C# Library.

Comment: If you're using OpenLDAP, then the `userAccountControl` attribute will have no meaning. You can't get around that.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look to the [ppolicy overlay](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-11.html). It is shipped with most openldap packages and has the features you are looking for.

Comment: I added `ppolicy overlay` in my OpenLdap but I am not able to read the attributes like `pwdMustChange` , `pwdLockout` etc. in c#

Comment: You must identify if your problem is a misconfiguration of OpenLDAP or something on the C# side. You can check if OpenLDAP has indeed the attributes you want by reading the available objectattributes with `ldapsearch -H ldaps://ldap.mydomain.tld -D cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=tld -W -x -s base -b cn=subschema + | grep pwdLockout` (you should adapt this command line to your situation of course). If you have some output then you should investigate on the C# side, if you have no output you should rework your OpenLDAP configuration.